# Issue with Triangulation Construction: Line Continuously Going Upwards

Tags: c++, math, triangulation

I'm facing an issue while constructing an area using triangulation. The area is being built correctly, and the inequalities that define its boundaries are also set up correctly. However, during the triangulation process, I encounter a line that continuously goes upwards. I have already checked my code and ensured that there are no errors in the triangulation algorithm or the inequality constraints.
The problem might be related to my approach in handling certain cases or the characteristics of the data I'm using to construct the area. I would like to ask for your assistance in understanding the possible cause of this issue and how to resolve it.Maybe the problem is an extra vertex in the stl file!If you have any ideas or assumptions about what might be causing this problem, or if you have encountered a similar situation before, please share your thoughts. I would appreciate any help or advice in resolving this issue!
The full code and image are attached below:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <functional>
#define pi  3.14159265358979323846
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
struct Point {
    double x, y;
};
int a = 0;
int b = 3;
int n = 10;
int m = 3;

// Saving the triangulation in STL format:
int savetostl(double* XX, double* YY, int** T, int size_T);
int savetostl(double* XX, double* YY, int** T, int size_T)
{
    int k = 0, ia, ib, ic;
    fstream TRstl;
    TRstl.open("triangulation.stl", ios::out | ios::app);
    TRstl.close();
    TRstl.open("triangulation.stl", ios::out | ios::in);
    TRstl << "solid <Triangulation>\n";
    for (k = 0; k <  size_T; k++)
    {
        ia = T[k][0];
        ib = T[k][1];
        ic = T[k][2];
        TRstl << "facet normal " << 0.0 << " " << 0.0 << " " << 1.0 << "\n";
        TRstl << "outer loop\n";
        TRstl << "vertex ";
        TRstl << XX[ia] << " " << YY[ia] << " " << 0.0 << "\n";
        TRstl << "vertex ";
        TRstl << XX[ib] << " " << YY[ib] << " " << 0.0 << "\n";
        TRstl << "vertex ";
        TRstl << XX[ic] << " " << YY[ic] << " " << 0.0 << "\n";
        TRstl << "endloop\n";
        TRstl << "endfacet\n";
    }
    TRstl << "endsolid";
    TRstl.close();
    return 0;
}

double F(double O) {
    return 3;
}

double Y(double O) {
    return 10;
}

double Gr(double O, double r) {
    return r * Y(O) + (1 - r) * F(O);
}

void Not_borderline(int**& T, int size_T, double*& X, double* &Y, int q) {

    int sizeT = size_T * q * q;
    int** newT = new int*[sizeT];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeT; i++) {
        newT[i] = new int[3];
    }
    double* NewX = new double[size_T * ((q + 2) * (q + 1) / 2)];
    double* NewY = new double[size_T * ((q + 2) * (q + 1) / 2)];
    int numbDot = 0;
    int numbRect = 0;
    double* ACDX = new double[q - 1]; // points on line AC
    double* ACDY = new double[q - 1];
    double* ABDX = new double[q - 1]; // points on line AB
    double* ABDY = new double[q - 1];
    double* internal_points_X = new double[(q - 1) * q / 2];
    double* internal_points_Y = new double[(q - 1) * q / 2];
    int numbDot = 0;
    int numbRect = 0;
double* ACDX = new double[q - 1]; //points on a straight line АС
    double* ACDY = new double[q - 1];
    double* ABDX = new double[q - 1]; // on a straight line AB
    double* ABDY = new double[q - 1];
    double* internal_points_X = new double[(q - 1) * q / 2];
    double* internal_points_Y = new double[(q - 1) * q / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < size_T; i++) //the main processing cycle of all triangles
    {
        Point a, b, c;
        a.x = X[T[i][0]];
        a.y = Y[T[i][0]];
        b.x = X[T[i][1]];
        b.y = Y[T[i][1]];
        c.x = X[T[i][2]];
        c.y = Y[T[i][2]];

        Point vectorAC;
        vectorAC.x = c.x - a.x;
        vectorAC.y = c.y - a.y;//guiding vector АС

        Point vectorAB;
        vectorAB.x = b.x - a.x;
        vectorAB.y = b.y - a.y;//guiding vector BС
        
       
        for (int i = 0; i < q - 1; i++) {
            ACDX[i] = ((i + 1) * vectorAC.x / q) + a.x;
        }
       
        for (int i = 0; i < q - 1; i++) {
            ACDY[i] = ((i + 1) * vectorAC.y / q) + a.y;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < q - 1; i++) {
            ABDX[i] = ((i + 1) * vectorAB.x / q) + a.x;
        }
       
        for (int i = 0; i < q - 1; i++) {
            ABDY[i] = ((i + 1) * vectorAB.y / q) + a.y;
        }//we fill arrays with points lying on straight lines ас и бс

        int k = 0;
        Point vectorABDACD;
        for (int i = 1; i < q; i++) {
            if (i != q - 1) {
                vectorABDACD.x = ACDX[i] - ABDX[i];
                vectorABDACD.y = ACDY[i] - ABDY[i];//vector of a straight line between points on AB и AC
            }
            else {
                vectorABDACD.x = c.x-b.x;
                vectorABDACD.y = c.y - b.y;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (i != q - 1) {
                    internal_points_X[k] = ABDX[i] + (j+1)*vectorABDACD.x/(i+1);
                    internal_points_Y[k] = ABDY[i] + (j + 1)* vectorABDACD.y / (i + 1);
                }
                else {
                    internal_points_X[k] = b.x + (j + 1) * vectorABDACD.x / (i + 1);
                    internal_points_Y[k] =b.y + (j + 1) * vectorABDACD.y / (i + 1); //points on straight lines between points on AB и AC
                }
                k++;
            }

        }
        int numbDotTEMP = numbDot;
        NewX[numbDot] = a.x;
        NewY[numbDot] = a.y;
        newT[numbRect][0] = numbDot;
        numbDot++;
        NewX[numbDot] = ABDX[0];
        NewY[numbDot] = ABDY[0];
        newT[numbRect][1] = numbDot;
        numbDot++;
        NewX[numbDot] = ACDX[0];
        NewY[numbDot] = ACDY[0];
        newT[numbRect][2] = numbDot;
        numbDot++;
        numbRect++;
        k = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < q; i++) {
            if (i != q - 1) {
                NewX[numbDot] = ABDX[i];
                NewY[numbDot] = ABDY[i];
                numbDot++;
            }
            else {
                NewX[numbDot] = b.x;
                NewY[numbDot] = b.y;
                numbDot++;
            }
            
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                NewX[numbDot] = internal_points_X[k];
                NewY[numbDot] = internal_points_Y[k];
                k++;
                numbDot++;
            }
            if (i != q - 1) {
                NewX[numbDot] = ACDX[i];
                NewY[numbDot] = ACDY[i];
                numbDot++;
            }
            else {
                NewX[numbDot] = c.x;
                NewY[numbDot] = c.y;
                numbDot++;
            }

        }
        numbDotTEMP++;

        for (int i = 0; i < q - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2 + i; j++) {
                newT[numbRect][0] = numbDotTEMP;
                newT[numbRect][1] = numbDotTEMP + 2 + i;
                newT[numbRect][2] = numbDotTEMP + 3 + i;
                cout << numbDotTEMP << "x=" << NewX[numbDotTEMP] << "     y=" << NewY[numbDotTEMP]<< " " << numbDotTEMP + 2 + i<<"x=" << NewX[numbDotTEMP + 2 + i] << "     y=" << NewY[numbDotTEMP + 2 + i] << " " << numbDotTEMP + 3 + i<< "x=" << NewX[numbDotTEMP + 3 + i] << "     y=" << NewY[numbDotTEMP + 3 + i] << endl;
                numbRect++;
                if (j > 0) {
                    newT[numbRect][0] = numbDotTEMP - 1;
                    newT[numbRect][1] = numbDotTEMP;
                    newT[numbRect][2] = numbDotTEMP + 2 + i;
                    cout << numbDotTEMP-2 << "x=" << NewX[numbDotTEMP - 2] << "     y=" << NewY[numbDotTEMP - 2] << " " << numbDotTEMP-1 << "x=" << NewX[numbDotTEMP - 1] << "     y=" << NewY[numbDotTEMP - 1] << " " << numbDotTEMP + 1 + i << "x=" << NewX[numbDotTEMP + 1 + i] << "     y=" << NewY[numbDotTEMP + 1 + i] << endl;
                    numbRect++;
                }
                numbDotTEMP++;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    delete[] ACDX;
    delete[] ABDX;
    delete[] ACDY;
    delete[] ABDY;
    delete[] internal_points_X;
    delete[] internal_points_Y;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_T; i++) {
        delete[] T[i];
    }
    delete[] T;
    delete[] X;
    delete[] Y;
    T = newT;
    X = NewX;
    Y = NewY;
}
// Limiting inequalities:
double F1(double x) {
    return x;
}
double G1(double x) {
    return pow(x,2);
}

int main()
{   
    // Arrays with coordinates: 
    double* X = new double[(n + 1) * (m + 1)];
    double* Y = new double[(n + 1) * (m + 1)];

    int i, j;
    int q = 3;
    int p = 2 * n * m;
    int** T = new int* [p]; // Array of vertices.

    // Forming a surface grid:
    int k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= m; j++) {
            X[k] = a + i * (b - a) / n;
            k++;
        }
    }

    k = 0;  
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= m; j++) {
            Y[k] = F1(X[i * (n + 1)]) + (G1(X[i * (n + 1)]) - F1(X[i * (n + 1)])) * j / m;
            k++;
        }
    }
    // Allocate memory for an array of vertices:
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        T[i] = new int[3];
    }
    
    // Filling in an array of vertices:
    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= n - 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= m - 1; j++) {
            T[k][0] = (m + 1) * i + j;
            T[k][1] = (m + 1) * (i + 1) + j;
            T[k][2] = (m + 1) * (i + 1) + j + 1;
            k++;
    
            T[k][0] = (m + 1) * i + j;
            T[k][1] = (m + 1) * (i + 1) + j + 1;
            T[k][2] = (m + 1) * (i)+j + 1;
            k++;
        }
    }
    
    i = n - 1;
    for (j = 0; j <= m - 1; j++) {
        T[k][0] = (m + 1) * i + j;
        T[k][1] = j;
        T[k][2] = j + 1;
        k++;

        T[k][0] = (m + 1) * i + j;
        T[k][1] = j + 1;
        T[k][2] = (m + 1) * (i)+j + 1;
        k++;
    }   

    // Let's perform a triangulation of the surface:
    Not_borderline(T, 2 * n * m, X, Y,3);
    // Let's save to a file:
    savetostl(X, Y, T,2*n*m*q); 
}
```

Image for example y-x>0 and y-x**2<0:
[image]

Comment: Hi Mosh, the above code seems to have some  duplicate declarations, however after correcting them and compiling/ running the code, if I then open the .stl file in meshlab, it looks fine (it indicates 36 faces and 30 vertices). I wonder how are you viewing the .stl file ?

Comment: I open through this site:https://www.viewstl.com/classic/        and select wireframe in it

Comment: OK wireframe shows the issue now. The line is actually a series of vertices, evenly spaced, all with the same 'x' value of zero, ranging from 0,0 to 0,4. What are your expected overall bounding vertices for the shape?

Comment: The expected bounding vertices for the figure you described would be:
Vertex 1: (0, 0)
Vertex 2: (0, 0.4)
Vertex 3: (0.4, 0)
Vertex 4: (0.4, 0.4)
This implies that the figure is a square formed by connecting these vertices with lines.

Comment: Maybe,it is not entirely clear what is meant. According to the points, it is confusing that the most extreme is located very far away.